# Model data not available to child thread

Tags: django

I am using Django-1.3 with the MySQL db engine.

In the setup for a unit test case (using manage.py to run the test), I create an object and save it.

If I query for the object (using objects.filter) from a response handler, I can see it fine.  If I create a child thread using the python threading module (threading.Thread) and it tries the same objects.filter call, it does not see the object.  Why would the child thread not see the entry I created in the unit test setup, when its visible in the parent thread?

Comment: It sounds like you are doing it right. Where do you query the database? Django creates an own database for the unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use TransactionTestCase instead of regular TestCase to do this. If you don't, the modifications that you carry out to the model in your test case (e.g. in your setup) will actually not be committed to the DB, hence not visible to your thread. See the [Django doc about TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#testcase) for more details.

Also, I have found out that the connection in the thread needs to be recreated. The following code did the trick:

```
from django.db import connection    
connection.close()
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

It is not your case, but should you use SQLite, you also need to specify a TEST_NAME in your settings. If not, Django SQLite DB is completely in memory, and cannot be shared among threads.

Using this approach, I could spawn a live test server in a thread while controlling selenium and DB from the spawning Django test case. I took the server thread code from [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2879)